# qmail, recover email from the mess folder

Tags: email

The server has Plesk 10 installed. It uses qmail as the email service. After a migration from Linux based system to Windows based system, qmail is broken. It can send email fine but can't receive any email. I have fixed the problem afterward but old emails before the fix applied are stuck in the mail queue. I found mail contents are placed in the mess folder of the qmail directory.

Before I try to write a program to extract those mail contents and resend them, if there has other way to fix those emails in the mail queue? I have tried qfixq but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Stop using qmail. It hasn't been updated in **14 years**, it's got security vulnerabilities, RFC violations, programming faults, and generally breaks for no good reason. Find something, anything else.

No this doesn't directly answer your question. But sometimes the correct answer is "don't do that"